# Using variable value inside xml tag in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to use a variable value inside an xml tag in Scala:

```
val currentEnv = "hadoop-uat-1"
val value = <property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs:// + currentEnv + :8020</value> <final>true</final></property>
```

But it doesn't work like this. Any idea on where I'm going wrong? Basically I don't want to hardcode the value because multiple env is present.

Comment: What do you mean by using? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamic variable with XML tags using `{variableName}` syntax

```
val currentEnv = "hadoop-uat-1"
val value = <property><name>fs.defaultFS</name><value>hdfs://{currentEnv}:8020</value> <final>true</final></property>
```